# Is there a way to set the path to the iTerm preferences folder directly from the shell?

Tags: iterm, preferences

So I know that you can set the path to the URL or folder for your preferences using the following path in iTerm2:

```
General > Preferences > 'Load preferences from a custom folder or URL'
```

but can this be done using just the terminal?